# django - aggregate json field specific keys and order by the aggregation

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-queryset, django-jsonfield

I have a model with the a field `data` of type `JSONField` from `django.contrib.postgres.fields`. The json structure is like so:

```
{'aa': 1, 'bb': 2, 'cc': 4}
```

I want to aggregate the sums of the `aa` and `cc` keys - so in this case, it will be 5. Also - i cannot promise that either `aa` or `cc` will be in the json. 

Is this possible? If so - i want to order by the aggregated data.

Example:

1. id: 1, data = {'aa': 1, 'bb': 2, 'cc':4}
2. id: 2, data = {'aa': 3, 'bb': 2}
3. id: 3, data = {'cc': 7}
4. id: 4, data = {'bb': 7}

I want to do a query, something like:
`MyModel.objects.aggregate(my_sum).order_by(my_sum)`
After aggregation the ordered rows in the queryset will be:

1. id: 3
2. id: 1
3. id: 2
4. id: 4

Thanks!

Comment: Which type of object(instance or queryset) you have of model ?

Comment: @NeErAjKuMaR - I have a queryset and i want to aggregate according to the model field and order by the aggregated value

Comment: but you said you need sum of keys  value from json data

Comment: @NeErAjKuMaR - I added an example to try and clarify my needs. Please let me know if this answers your question.

Comment: you ordered queryset according to sum of aa and cc keys right?

Comment: @NeErAjKuMaR - yes.

Answer (score 2):

I understood that you want to sum up a value and b value for each row and then order each row by sum value. right?

`-> ->>` This is how to select key or value in JSON format in PostgreSQL(I don't know if it also works in MySQL or others, I normally worked with PostgreSQL).
There is good resource in [here](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-json/). your data in a column named '`data`' is `{"aa":3, "bb":2, "cc":5}`. so you select aa value by `data->>'aa'`. What if `{'classification':{'pc':5000}}`? you need to select pc value. Then `data->'classification'->>'pc'`

:: notation is cast operation.

```
CAST(data->'aa' AS INTEGER)

data->'aa'::int
```

class RawSQL(sql, params, output_field=None)

RawSQL("((data->>'aa'::int), (0,)") doesn't mean that if aa doesn't exist, it has 0 value. 0 is params.

```
queryset.annotate(val=RawSQL("select col from sometable where othercol = %s", (someparam,)))
```

Well, if you can modify your data like this

- id: 1, data = {'aa': 1, 'bb': 2, 'cc':4}
- id: 2, data = {'aa': 3, 'bb': 2, 'cc':0}
- id: 3, data = {'cc': 7, 'bb': 0, 'cc':0}
- id: 4, data = {'bb': 7, 'bb': 0, 'cc':0}

This can work.

```
Contract.objects.annotate(
sumVal=RawSQL("((data->>'aa')::int)", (0,))+RawSQL("((data->>'cc')::int)",(0,)))
.order_by('sumVal')
```

---

## I suggested using Coalesce. the author of this question figured out. There is code below.

```
raw_sql = "+".join(["COALESCE((data->>%s)::int, 0)" for _ in ['aa', 'cc']) 
MyMoodel.objects.all()
.annotate(my_sum=RawSQL(raw_sql, params=('aa', 'cc')))
.order_by('my_sum')
```

Comment: I tried to figure out with Coalesce to cover the case when key 'aa' or 'cc' doesn't exist. It is interesting question, So I spent quite time to figure out but I couldn't. you can check [django manual about Coalesce](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/database-functions/#coalesce). I hope it gives you any idea to solve your problem.

Comment: So i figured it out how to use Coalesce. This is the statements i used:
`raw_sql = "+".join(["COALESCE((data->>%s)::int, 0)" for _ in ['aa', 'cc'])`
And then just run 
`MyMoodel.objects.all().annotate(my_sum=RawSQL(raw_sql, params=('aa', 'cc'))).order_by('my_sum')`
Please Update your answer and i would be happy to mark it as the answer

Comment: Oh did it work? Cool. I tried to put COALESCE in annotate and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

```
 YourModel.objects.annotate(aa=RawSQL("((data->>'aa')::int)", (0,)),
                            cc=RawSQL("((data->>'cc')::int)", (0,))) \
                .aggregate(total=Sum('aa')+Sum('cc')).order_by('total')
```