# Django get keys, values from dict and add them to query

Tags: django, django-models

I'm wondering if there is a good way to achieve this:

```
class Notification(models.Model):
    target_clients_query = JSONField(blank=True)
```

I have a model with a JSONField (I could change this). It keeps the query of Client objects that will receive a Notification.

```
class Client(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=False, related_name='client_profile', db_index=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15, db_index=True, blank=True)
    cart = models.ForeignKey(Cart, null=True, blank=True, related_name='client', db_index=True)
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to=get_uuid_client_image)
    facebook_user_id = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=250)
    email_order_notifications = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    current_sector = models.ForeignKey("Sector", null=True)
```

I would like to save the query data in the JSONField and then, when I process the Notification objects, get the corresponding clients to send notification to:

```
from datetime import datetime
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from app.misuper.models import Notification

class Command(BaseCommand):
    """
    Sends notifications to users
    """
    def handle(self, *args, **options):

        actual_time = datetime.today()
        notifications_to_send = Notification.objects.filter(sent=False, programmed_date__lte=actual_time.today())

        for notification in notifications_to_send:
            if notification.target_client:
                notification.send_notification()
            else:
                clients_query = notification.target_clients_query
                for key, value in clients_query:
                    pass
                    # Query the Client's model with the filters in the clients query dict
```

Comment: is it fine to use RawSQL combining with annotate method?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45316015/6568309 check this please. You can filter your JSON data with RawSQL and Annotate method.